# JSON parse not converted in same order in ruby

Tags: json, hash, ruby-1.8.7

Below JSON Response

```
{"-LESlrKUjoS6_SQuplCr":{"arr_url":"","chat_date":"2018-06-08T08:03:46+03:00","employee_id":696,"f_name":"","guardian_id":"3778","message":"hii","sender":"employee"},"-LESmcgBNTuYMS015qXq":{"arr_url":"","chat_date":"2018-06-08T08:07:08+03:00","employee_id":696,"f_name":"","guardian_id":"3778","message":"fffffff","sender":"employee"},"-LESmrNMINsMgL_gFoHF":{"arr_url":"https://test.s3.amazonaws.com","chat_date":"2018-06-08T08:08:08+03:00","employee_id":696,"f_name":"AA.png","guardian_id":"3778","message":"vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv","sender":"employee"},"-LESnhlwWepa96SABV6Q":{"arr_url":"","chat_date":"2018-06-08T08:11:50+03:00","employee_id":696,"f_name":"","guardian_id":"3778","message":"BBBBBBBBBBBBBB","sender":"employee"},"-LETIw0V5fckwIJXP4Ai":{"arr_url":"","chat_date":"2018-06-08T10:32:37+03:00","employee_id":696,"f_name":"","guardian_id":"3778","message":"asdasdasd","sender":"employee"},"-LETIzFK1AX62B0NeHn6":{"arr_url":"","chat_date":"2018-06-08T10:32:51+03:00","employee_id":696,"f_name":"","guardian_id":"3778","message":"dasdasdasdasd","sender":"employee"},"-LETJ-y0t-pzQwqoAgn7":{"arr_url":"","chat_date":"2018-06-08T10:32:58+03:00","employee_id":696,"f_name":"","guardian_id":"3778","message":"vvvvvvvvvvvvvv","sender":"employee"}}
```

After Converting into hash order of hash elements not as json

```
{"-LETIw0V5fckwIJXP4Ai"=>{"sender"=>"employee", "f_name"=>"", "arr_url"=>"", "chat_date"=>"2018-06-08T10:32:37+03:00", "message"=>"asdasdasd", "employee_id"=>696, "guardian_id"=>"3778"}, "-LESmrNMINsMgL_gFoHF"=>{"sender"=>"employee", "f_name"=>"AA.png", "arr_url"=>"https://test.s3.amazonaws.com", "chat_date"=>"2018-06-08T08:08:08+03:00", "message"=>"vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv", "employee_id"=>696, "guardian_id"=>"3778"}, "-LESnhlwWepa96SABV6Q"=>{"sender"=>"employee", "f_name"=>"", "arr_url"=>"", "chat_date"=>"2018-06-08T08:11:50+03:00", "message"=>"BBBBBBBBBBBBBB", "employee_id"=>696, "guardian_id"=>"3778"}, "-LESlrKUjoS6_SQuplCr"=>{"sender"=>"employee", "f_name"=>"", "arr_url"=>"", "chat_date"=>"2018-06-08T08:03:46+03:00", "message"=>"hii", "employee_id"=>696, "guardian_id"=>"3778"}, "-LETJ-y0t-pzQwqoAgn7"=>{"sender"=>"employee", "f_name"=>"", "arr_url"=>"", "chat_date"=>"2018-06-08T10:32:58+03:00", "message"=>"vvvvvvvvvvvvvv", "employee_id"=>696, "guardian_id"=>"3778"}, "-LETIzFK1AX62B0NeHn6"=>{"sender"=>"employee", "f_name"=>"", "arr_url"=>"", "chat_date"=>"2018-06-08T10:32:51+03:00", "message"=>"dasdasdasdasd", "employee_id"=>696, "guardian_id"=>"3778"}, "-LESmcgBNTuYMS015qXq"=>{"sender"=>"employee", "f_name"=>"", "arr_url"=>"", "chat_date"=>"2018-06-08T08:07:08+03:00", "message"=>"fffffff", "employee_id"=>696, "guardian_id"=>"3778"}}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I want generated hash elements to be in the same order of as JSON , which are already in sorted order based into chat_date

Comment: Try to remove hyphen before LE, prefix symbols or numbers in keys in json format may trigger different order.

Comment: still doesnt make any difference